# how to excract a component from gcv function

Tags: r

I want to take only the gcv value from the `gcv` function provided with Locfit package that makes a call to locfit() and exctract these components:

```
 >mm=gcv(VS~RE, data=base, alpha=0.5)
 >mm
    lik       infl     vari      gcv
 -4.53376  7.013307  6.487449  0.1216589
```

And mm$gcv doesn't work.
how to get only the gcv value?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a normal vector. See if `mm["gcv"]` works.